# Opencart paypal standard not processing

Tags: paypal, opencart

I've googled like crazy and can't find a solution. I'm using opencart 1.5.5.1 with paypal standard. It processes and returns to the site and the site says the order has been processed. However, nothing shows up in the users order history or in the admin dashboard. Here's a rundown of the settings.

- Transaction method - sale
- All statuses set to match their title, i.e completed status set to complete
- status set to enabled

On paypal website preferences

- Auto Return: on
- return URL http://www.mydomain.com/store/index.php?route=payment/pp_standard/callback
- Payment data transfer: on
- encrypted website payments: off
- express checkout: no
- instant payment notification url: http://www.mydomain.com/store/index.php?route=payment/pp_standard/callback

So the core issue is that the users get's taken to paypal and get's returned to the website after paying, however, an order does not show up on either the user's end, or on the owner/admin's side. Anyone have any ideas what might be causing the trouble?

Comment: What do You mean by `nothing shows up in the users order history or in the admin dashboard`? Like the order status does not change or the order is acting like it was not payed or that the order gets deleted? Or?

Comment: Are you getting any type of transaction id back from PayPal?

Comment: @shadyyx there is just not any record of an order from either the customer side or the admin side. If the customer were to go into order history right after the payment is processed nothing shows up. Same thing from the admin sign, there is just never any sign of an order.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad, I'm pretty new to the paypal api, is that something I would have to setup? If I were getting anything back it would be in the return URLs that I put in my description above, those are the only things I setup on paypal

Comment: @loveforvdubs That means that the order is not confirmed. Confirmation is done right by pay method after is correctly processed and the payment is done. Looking into `catalog/controller/payment/pp_standard.php` I can see a method `callback()` that should be called after the payment is processed and that contains a `$this->model_checkout_order->confirm(/*...*/);` call - so probably the payment is not processed correctly and that's why the order is not being confirmed. Look at the `order` table - there would be records for the missing orders - but until they are confirmed they do not show...

Comment: @loveforvdubs I am using `PayPal Standard`, too, with no problems... But I do not have many of the options You mention above - are You sure You are not using `PayPal Website Payment Pro` instead?

Comment: Thanks @shadyyx, it sounds like maybe the problem is in the callback url. I'll take a look at those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out. It was all because I had my webstore password protected. I didn't want it to be ope to the public while I was developing it and this is what was causing the payments not to callback to my webstore. Thanks everyone for all the help!